# Filtering results by model in Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm building simple forum with Laravel 4. I need to count posts written by current user on given topic.

What I have so far:

```
$topic = Topic::find(1);
$user = Auth::user();
echo $user->posts()->whereTopicId($topic->id);
```

This works fine, but I'm not satisfied with working on ID directly. Is it possible to do it in neat way using relations?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
echo $user->posts()->whereTopic($topic);
```

Which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you could achieve `$user->posts()->whereTopic($topic)` by using [scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) in your `Post` Model

```
public function scopeTopic($query, $topic)
{
    return $query->where('topic_id', '=', $topic->id);
}
```